# Ошибка No such file or directory

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу шуточного бота для телеграмма. Сначала все работало прекрасно, но, после введения второй функции, стало выдавать ошибку:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

не смотря на то, что отдельные файлы не используются

```py
import telebot as t

bot = t.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'text {message.from_user.first_name}'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mess, parse_mode='html')


@bot.massage_handler()
def get_fuck(message):
    if  message.text == 'text' or message == 'text' or message == 'text' or message == 'text':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'text', parse_mode='html')
bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```